# How to post multiple fields values when clicking over a checkbox

Tags: php, checkbox

I am working in a small project and I have a code to do a multiple post of fields values when clicking over a check box. I have a table which lists classes and time. I need to know how to click over a checkbox and send class and time values at same time using a loop.

This is driving me crazy. I have spent hours and I can't figure out how to send multiple values at same time. When I check all the values, it works perfect but if I click one or two values, I always get a wrong time value shown.

Here is the PHP code, I am using:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if((!empty($_POST['class'])) && (!empty($_POST['time']))) {

$checked_count = count($_POST['class']);
echo "You have selected following ".$checked_count." option(s): <br/>";

// Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.

for ($i=0; $i < $checked_count; $i++) {
echo $_POST['class'][$i]. " ";
echo $_POST['time'][$i]. "<br>";
}
}
}
else{
echo "<b>Please Select At least One Option.</b>";
}
```

Here is my HTML CODE:

```
<form action="checkclass.php" method="post">

<label class="heading">Select Your Technical Exposure:</label><br />
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="class[]" value="C/C++"><label>C/C++</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="time[]" value="1"  width="15"><br /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="class[]" value="Java"><label>Java</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="time[]" value="2"  width="15"><br /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="class[]" value="PHP"><label>PHP</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="time[]" value="3" width="15"><br /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="class[]" value="HTML/CSS"><label>HTML/CSS</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="time[]" value="2"  width="15"><br /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="class[]" value="LINUX"><label>UNIX/LINUX</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="time[]" value="3"  width="15"><br /></td>
</tr>

<input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Submit"/>


</form>
```

If I check all the values. I get the following result:

### Class       Time

C/C++,        1
Java,         2
PHP,          3
HTML/CSS,     2
UNIX/LINUX,   3

If I only check the UNIX/LINUX class I get:

### Class         Time

UNIX/LINUX,   1

I get 1 for LInux time when it should be 3. I think the time field takes the first position in the array when click just one class.

How do I relate time and class values so that whole values in a row are posted at same time. I really want to do a multiple insert but I think solving this will help me.

I will appreciate any help with this matter.

Comment: What are getting when you run this code ?

Comment: That is what you wanted to achieve... Right ??

Comment: If I check all the values. I get the following result:
Class       Time
----------------
C/C++,        1    
Java,         2
PHP,          3
HTML/CSS,     2
UNIX/LINUX,   3

If I only check the UNIX/LINUX class I get:

Class         Time
----------------
UNIX/LINUX,   1

I get 1 for LInux time when it should be 3. I think the time field takes the first position in the array when selecting just one class.

Comment: The problem is when I select just one option class. I get the class value right but a wrong time value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


    if((count($_POST['class']) > 0) && (count($_POST['time']) > 0)) {

        $checked_count = count($_POST['class']);
        echo "You have selected following ".$checked_count." option(s): <br/>";

        // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.

        foreach ($_POST['class'] as $k => $v) {
            echo $_POST['class'][$k]. " ";
            echo $_POST['time'][$k]. "<br>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "<b>Please Select At least One Option and the Number of Years of Technical Exposure.</b>";
    }
}   

?>
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<form action="checkclass.php" method="post">

<label class="heading">Select Your Technical Exposure:</label><br />
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="class[0]" value="C/C++"><label>C/C++</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="time[0]" value="1"  width="15"><br /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="class[1]" value="Java"><label>Java</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="time[1]" value="2"  width="15"><br /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="class[2]" value="PHP"><label>PHP</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="time[2]" value="3" width="15"><br /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="class[3]" value="HTML/CSS"><label>HTML/CSS</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="time[3]" value="2"  width="15"><br /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="class[4]" value="LINUX"><label>UNIX/LINUX</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="time[4]" value="3"  width="15"><br /></td>
</tr>

<input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Submit"/>


</form>
```

It worked for me. Let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: Vagabond thank you very much. It works as expected. 
What about If I am getting the table results from a data base using a loop. Should I create a counter loop and assign the same number to the class and time to get a similar result as you did?

Comment: My pleasure.
Will you be getting the values in the same way ? In that case just make sure that the keys in both arrays for the corresponding values are the same. You don't need to have another loop.